# How to export spaces from confluence 5.8.5 to 5.9.7?

Tags: confluence

We are using confluence 5.8.5 server version for our internally small teams in my company.But, we got an order to move our confluence to enterprise-confluence handled by another large confluence admin team in our company. So, I thought the best way is to just export each space to xml and import in the enterprise one. I tried to export one space and I got below error.

> There was an error in the export. Please check your log files. :java.io.IOException: No space left on device

I observed that I do not have space in my confluence 5.8.5 in "/var" mount. I raised request to increase space which may take 3 business days. As a workaround is there any way I can export the space to any other mount or just directly from UI to my desktop like we do for jira?

Answer (score 1):

Exporting and importing Space in Confluence needs free storage space in the Server. Other than that, exporting/importing space and site requires free memory as well so please ensure that you allocated enough memory to JVM. I believe you have to wait for extra storage at this stage.

Also,practically importing to next major version is not a good practice for Confluence. I would try it in a test environment prior to importing directly to production.